# How do I get the count of distinct values in the first row of the result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I want to check if the colour and city are multiple for a document for the highest amount. if yes, I want to set a bit as 1 and if not, it should be 0

Sample data:

```
Code doc year amount colour city
AB   123 2021 485    Red    Paris
AB   123 2021 416    Red    Paris
AB   123 2021 729    Red    London
AB   123 2021 645    Red    Bengaluru
```

Expected output:
I want the output in one row

```
Code Doc Year Amount Colour City  Col_Mul City_Mul 
AB   123 2021 729    Red    London 0       1
```

Amount, Colour and city should be the maximum one.

What I tried:
To get the data in one row, I used the row number and ordered by the maximum amount and selected the data where the row number is one. But after that I used dense rank for the Colour and City column. But I didn't get the expected output.

Comment: Please show us the actual query you tried. And if you provide your sample data as DDL+DML you make it *much* easier for people to assist you.

Comment: Why not simple `GROUP BY`?

Comment: The GROUP BY statement is often used with aggregate functions (COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM, AVG) to group the result-set by one or more columns.

Comment: If you use MAX you can probably get them. I can't quite work out what you are doing though.

Comment: In the expected output, I should get only one row for the sample data. It is easy for me to get until the city column. I’m facing problems with the last two columns. If there are multiple colours, the col_Mul column should be set to 1, if not 0. Here we have only one colour so it is 0. Similarly we have 3 distinct cities which indicates there are multiple cities and hence it should be 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CROSS APPLY and get data as given below:

Thanks @Gayani for test data.

```sql
select TOPROW.*,case when T1.colorcount > 1 THEN 1 else 0 end as Multi_color,
 case when T2.citycount > 1 THEN 1 else 0 end as Multi_city
 from
 (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tes_firstRow
 order by amount desc) as toprow
cross apply
(
SELECT count(distinct color) from tes_firstrow WHERE doc = toprow.doc
) as t1(colorcount)
cross apply
(
SELECT count(distinct city) from tes_firstrow WHERE doc = toprow.doc
) as t2(citycount)
```

| Code | doc | year | amount | color | City | Multi_color | Multi_city |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AB | 123 | 2021 | 729 | RED | LONDON | 0 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code sample will help you with this.
Please try the below code and let me know if it helps with what you need. I used temporary tables here. You can use any of the technology to build the logic. CTE (Common table expressions) or derived tables.

```
CREATE TABLE tes_firstRow
(
    Code varchar(100)
    , doc int
    , [year] int
    , amount int
    , color varchar(100)
    , City varchar(100)
)

insert into  tes_firstRow values  ('AB', 123,2021,485,'RED','PARIS')
insert into  tes_firstRow values  ('AB', 123,2021,416,'RED','PARIS')
insert into  tes_firstRow values  ('AB', 123,2021,729,'RED','LONDON')
insert into  tes_firstRow values  ('AB', 123,2021,645,'RED','BENGALURU')

SELECT 
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY  Code, doc,[year] ORDER BY amount DESC) AS [rank]
    ,Code
    ,doc
    ,[year]
    ,amount
    ,color
    ,City 
INTO #temp_1
FROM tes_firstRow


 SELECT 
 [#temp_1].[Code]
 ,[#temp_1].[doc]
 ,[#temp_1].[year]
 ,[#temp_1].[amount]
 ,[#temp_1].[color]
 ,[#temp_1].[City]
 , (Select COUNT(Distinct [#temp_1].[color] ) where  [#temp_1].[rank] = 1 ) as Col_Mul
 , (Select COUNT(Distinct [#temp_1].[City]) where  [#temp_1].[rank] = 1)  as City_Mul
 ,1 as City_Mul
 FROM  #temp_1 
 WHERE #temp_1.[rank] = 1
  group by   [#temp_1].[Code]
    ,[#temp_1].[doc]
    ,[#temp_1].[year]
    ,[#temp_1].[amount]
    ,[#temp_1].[color]
    ,[#temp_1].[City]
     ,[#temp_1].[rank] 

     DROP TABLE #temp_1

 Result:
```

[image: Result:]

Comment: I should get the city name of the highest amount

Comment: Don't you think that you have hard coded the last two expected columns?

Comment: I changed the code and added again. But I think cross apply work better.  Thanks. Ill try to change the code and add again if I could find a better one than this.

Comment: @BharathKumar, if you can explain the last two columns it is so helpful. What you need to get from those two columns?

Answer (score 0):

There you go. Weird requirement though...

```
SELECT T.Code, Doc, Year, MAX(T.Amount) Amount,
      (SELECT TOP 1 Colour FROM T as X WHERE Amount = MAX(T.Amount)) Colour,
      (SELECT TOP 1 City FROM T as X WHERE Amount = MAX(T.Amount)) City,
      CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT T.Colour) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Col_Mul,
      CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT T.City) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as City_Mul
FROM T
GROUP BY T.Code, Doc, Year
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want window functions combined with conditional aggregation:

```
select code, doc, year, max(amount),
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then color end) as color,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then city end) as city,
       (case when seqnum = 1 and color_count > 1 then 1 else 0 end) as color_dup,
       (case when seqnum = 1 and city_count > 1 then 1 else 0 end) as city_dup,
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by code, doc, year order by amount desc) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by code, doc, year, color) as color_count,
             count(*) over (partition by code, doc, year, city) as city_count
      from t
     ) t
group by code, doc, year;
```

I'm not actually sure if you want `1` when the value is duplicated or not, so those values might be backwards.